# What is causing this segfault?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I get a segfault after calling `mygets()`. Here is my code:

```
    #include <termios.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct _charlist{
        char ch;
        struct _charlist *next;
    }charlist;
    
    static struct termios old, new;
    void mygets(char** p);
    char getche(void); 
    char getch_(int echo);
    void resetTermios(void);
    void initTermios(int echo);
    
    
    int main(void){
        char *p;
        
        printf("\nWho loves orange soda?: ");
        mygets(&p);
        printf("'%s' loves orange soda!", p);
    }
    
    
    void mygets(char** p){
        char c;
        charlist *root, *curr;
        unsigned i, count=0;
    
        root=NULL;
    
    while((c = getche()) != '\n'){      
    
        count++;    
        if(!root){ 
            root = (charlist*) malloc(sizeof(charlist));
            root->ch = c;
                root->next = NULL;
                curr = root;
            }
    
            else{
                curr
->next = (charlist*) malloc(sizeof(charlist));
                curr->next->ch = c;
                curr->next->next = NULL;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
    
        //now request string space.
        *p = (char*) malloc((count+1)*sizeof(char));
    
        printf("\np is now malloced");      //This line doesn't get printed!
        
        //move linked list into string space.
        curr = root;
        for(i=0; i<=count; i++){
            *p[i] = curr->ch;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    
        //null-terminate the string.
        *p[i] = '\0';
    
    }
```

Can someone tell me why I get a segfault?

I can't post this question unless the ratio of code to question is lower than some arbitrary threshold.  Therefore, there now follows the first paragraph of Alice in Wonderland, for your consideration.

> Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
> bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into
> the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
> conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice
> 'without pictures or conversation?'

Comment: `func()` does not affect `p` in `main()`.  `printf("'%s'", p);` is UB.

Comment: I bet it's not that line; I bet it's the printf line.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace from a debugger session. (And side note: if you can't guarantee that count is "small" i.e. when count is provided by a user make sure to check for an overflow in the multiplication)

Comment: In addition to Alexander's answer, you should not cast the result of malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @johannes Since `sizeof(char)` is 1, `sizeof(char)*(count+1)` has little change of overflowing due to multiplication.

Comment: You need to post the code that "gives a string" to `p`, as it may be causing your segfaults.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen If I put a printf("I'm here!") after the line I suspect, it doesn't print.  I get a segfault error instead. That's how I know the segfault happens there.

Comment: This code is either incomplete or plain wrong, in both versions. Why should printf do anything but fault given a pointer to a raw block of memory?

Comment: @david.pfx The segfault happens before it returns to printf().

Comment: @KorganRivera: UB is shorthand for the dreaded [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984). Please read that Q&A carefully. BTW: Do not use `sizeof(char)`, just write 1, if anything at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator TIL UB.  I was just using sizeof in case magic happened, and char became several bytes. :)

Comment: @KorganRivera: Well, if you have UB, 1 may be 2, sure ;-) Still, I think time-travel is funnier: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx

Comment: @KorganRivera as @chux mentioned, `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1. No matter what.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen In any case, it's not the question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
*p[i] = curr->ch;
```

Should be:

```
(*p)[i] = curr->ch;
```

You want to access the `i`'th character of where `p` is pointing to.  Not dereference the `i`th pointer in an array of pointers.

Same problem with `*p[i] = '\0';` later.

Also you did not malloc enough space, as your loop writes `count + 1` characters and then you write an extra null terminator, so you should either malloc `count + 2` or adjust your loop to finish at `i<count`, not `i<=count`. (probably the latter).

Also, it'd be useful to check `curr != NULL` before dereferencing it, so that if you do have an off-by-one error then you don't get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

When `func` is called, it is passed a *copy* of the local variable `p` in `main`. This copy is then assigned the `malloc`ed area in `func`. The original `p` in the `main` is never modified, so its contents remain undefined, causing a segmentation fault when `printf` dereferences `p` in order to print the string.

You may want `func` to return a `char*` pointing to the newly malloc'd area.

Comment: Noteworthy: the `char *p` in `void func(char* p)` does not do much useful here.

Comment: So to change the pointer in main() I would need to pass a pointer to the pointer?

Comment: I think Vlad's response even has a code sample for it?

Comment: @AlexanderGessler That's what I used.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the argument to the function by value. So according to the function declaration

```
void func(char* p);
```

parameter p is a local variable of the function that will be destroyed after exiting the function. Any changes of the local variable do not influence on the argument.

You could define the function the following ways

```
char * func(){
    unsigned count = 10;
    char *p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1));

    //p is given a string after this, but problem is the above line.

   return p;
}
```

and call it as

```
p = funct();
```

or

```
void func(char ** p){
    unsigned count = 10;
    *p = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1));

    //p is given a string after this, but problem is the above line.
}
```

and call it as

```
func( &p );
```

Comment: Your second example was what I was trying to do.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you zero-terminate the string?

Comment: @AlexanderGessler Yep!  But like I said, the segfault happens before I do anything with p.  That's what's confusing me.

Comment: Even better would be `*p = malloc( sizeof **p * (count + 1));`